# Internet Explorer 11 favourite bar greyed out

Tags: internet-explorer, active-directory, internet-explorer-11, gpo, favorite

in IE 11, the Favourites Bar greyed out.  I suspect maybe related to following GPOs that I applied:

**1. Set IE Home Page:** 
GPO->User Configuration -> Policies -> Administrative Templates -> WindowsComponents -> Internet Explorer->Disable changing home page settings->Enable

**2. Add favourite URL:**
GPO->User Configuration -> Preferences->Windows Settings->Shortcuts

However, I can't see anything wrong with those 2 GPO. But how come all of sudden favourites bar is disabled?

**Update - Add screenshot **

[image: IE Toolbar]

Comment: How did you define your shortcut properties under #2?  Can you send a screenshot of the General tab of the "New Shortcut Properties" dialog box which comes up when you go to the path for #2.  Please be specific as possible and I will try to reproduce.

Comment: thanks heron, I have added the screenshot. Hope helps

Comment: I just did the same actions as you and was unable to reproduce.  Are you sure your IE Toolbar isn't locked?  (IE > View > Toolbars > uncheck "Lock the toolbars")

Comment: It is unlocked. as the issue only happens to favourite bar, otherwise, it would happen to all toolbar. See updated screenshot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After long time without getting answer from anywhere, today, I accidentally found the solution myself.

Step 1: run gpresult to find which group policy blocked favourite bar. It turned out it is called: Default Domain Policy, and there is a setting called Turn Off Favourites Bar. The state of the policy is Enabled. As I mentioned before, I never did anything to this policy, not sure how it got activated. Perhaps triggered by the 2 other group policy as a MS bug?

Step 2: on domain controller, run gpedit, go to user configuration>administrative templates>windows components>internet Explorer>turn that policy off.

The favourites bar is now showing up.